# Locale switch in login of FOSUserBundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm trying to get locale switching to work in the login screen of my application. In order to do that I have links on my login page that point to site.com/ (the default locale) and site.com/en (the second locale I support). As soon as I've logged in, the switching works like a charm. However if I'm not yet authenticated the login always goes back to the default locale. My understanding was that if I use the named routes from FOSUserBundle then it's should be able to handle the locales automatically, but I can't get it to work.

My app/config/security.yml

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
                login_path: fos_user_security_login
                check_path: fos_user_security_check
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/_wdt, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }         # allow wdt for debugging
        - { path: ^/_profiler/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }    # allow profiler for debugging
        - { path: ^/bundles/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }      # allow assets to be loaded anonymously

        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_USER }
```

My app/config/routing.yml

```
# FOS User bundle
fos_user_security:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"

fos_user_profile:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/profile.xml"
    prefix: /profile

#fos_user_register:
#    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml"
#    prefix: /register

fos_user_resetting:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/resetting.xml"
    prefix: /resetting

fos_user_change_password:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/change_password.xml"
    prefix: /profile
```

Any pointers much appreciated as I've been stuck with this for a couple of days now

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know how you're handling the locale detection/switch but with [JMSI18nRoutingBundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSI18nRoutingBundle) you can do as below.

Add the required bundles to `composer.json`:

```
"require": {
    ...
    "jms/i18n-routing-bundle": "1.1.*",
    "jms/translation-bundle": "1.1.*",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "1.3.*"
},
```

Configure the bundles:

```
jms_i18n_routing:
    default_locale: en
    locales: [en, fr, it, sp]
    strategy: prefix
```

Bootstrap the bundles:

```
$bundles = array(
    ...
    new JMS\I18nRoutingBundle\JMSI18nRoutingBundle(),
    new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
);
```

Modify existing routes to prefix them with the desired locale:

```
access_control:
    # Routes are prefixed by ther user locale.
    - { path: ^/[^/]+/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/[^/]+/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/[^/]+/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/[^/]+/admin, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/[^/]+/, role: ROLE_USER }
```

Now it should work!

Comment: thanks for the tip on the JMS bundle, I will try this approach next week when I return to this project.

Comment: I used this setup to configure my multilanguage site. but all tough my login page is available in all languages I get redirected to the front page without any locale after login. Any ideas?

Answer (score 12):

The solution ended up being to prefix the locale to the route imports of FOSUserBundle:

```
# FOS User bundle
fos_user_security:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"
    prefix: /{_locale}

fos_user_profile:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/profile.xml"
    prefix: /{_locale}/profile

fos_user_register:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml"
    prefix: /{_locale}/register

fos_user_resetting:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/resetting.xml"
    prefix: /{_locale}/resetting

fos_user_change_password:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/change_password.xml"
    prefix: /{_locale}/profile
```

And also change the firewall to allow locales in the anonymous routes and configure the logout_path:

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
                login_path: fos_user_security_login
                check_path: fos_user_security_check
            logout:
                path:   fos_user_security_logout
            anonymous:    true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/_wdt, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }         # allow wdt for debugging
        - { path: ^/_profiler/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }    # allow profiler for debugging
        - { path: ^/bundles/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }      # allow assets to be loaded anonymously

        - { path: ^/[a-z]+/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/[a-z]+/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/[a-z]+/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_USER } # this must be the last match, as url patterns are checked in the order they appear
```

Using the JMSI18nRoutingBundle would probably be better in the long term, but it did not work as a drop in solution when I tried it and the budget for this project did not allow me to start figuring out why not, so that will be left for a future update.

Comment: Still working with Symfony 3 / FOS UserBundle 2.1.2. I also had to add the lines `login_path: fos_user_security_login` and  `check_path: fos_user_security_check` as shown in the code above.

Answer (score 2):

My solution:
You have to redefine the fos_user routes for the be_simple_i18n type format.
(I chose the yaml version):

In app/config/routing.yml

```
[...]
#register the path to the file with the be_simple_i18n type fos_user routes
fos_user:       
    resource: "config/routing/fos_user_i18n.yml"
    type: be_simple_i18n

my_yaml_i18n_routes:
    resource: "config/routing/i18n.yml"
    type: be_simple_i18n
```

In app/Resources/config/routing/fos_user_i18n.yml:

```
#you have to make entries for all the fos_user routes here!
#you can find them all in vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/Resources/routing
fos_user_security_login:
    locales:  { en: "/login", de: "/anmelden" }
    defaults: { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Security:login }
fos_user_security_check:
    locales:  { en: "/login_check", de: "/login_pruefung" }
    defaults: { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Security:check }
#...
```

In app/config/security.yml

```
firewalls:       
    [...]

    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            login_path: fos_user_security_login
            check_path: fos_user_security_check
            csrf_provider: security.csrf.token_manager # Use form.csrf_provider instead for Symfony <2.4

        logout:
            path: fos_user_security_logout
            target: #where_no_one_has_gone_before
        [...]

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/anmelden$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/registrieren, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    [...]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling a bit with this issue. I wanted to have the pure login (no URL in the session) to be redirected to the proper localized page. 
I could find the answer in the Symfony documentation:

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
# ...
 firewalls:
    main:
        form_login:
            # ...
            default_target_path: index [ or your named route ]
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, could you post a link to the relevant resource?