# How to redirect to default locale URL?

Tags: symfony, internationalization, yaml, fosuserbundle

I have a translated project with `FOSUserBundle` installed. When a user try to access to a specific URL, he is redirected to the login form. This is the main firewall configuration in `security.yml` (the firewall used by `FOSUserBundle`):

```
        main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login: 
            login_path: /%locale%/login
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
        logout:       true
        anonymous:    true
```

And it seems to work fine, but the default `%locale%` (es) has to redirect to `/login`, since `/es/login` doesn't exist.

How could I achieve it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17207463/locale-switch-in-login-of-fosuserbundle should help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code works right:

```
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login: 
            login_path: fos_user_security_login
            check_path: fos_user_security_check
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
        logout:
            path: fos_user_security_logout
            target: fos_user_security_login
        anonymous:    true
```