# FOSUser mail is translated but confirmation_url isn't

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I found an easy way of adding a locale to my Symfony routes, as described here: [Locale switch in login of FOSUserBundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17207463/locale-switch-in-login-of-fosuserbundle)

Some relevant settings in my project:

**config**

`framework:
    translator:      { fallback: "%locale%" }
    default_locale: nl`

**services**

`fosmailer: @fos_user.mailer.twig_swift`

**routing**

`fos_user_register:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml"
    prefix: /{_locale}/registreren`

I'm trying to get FOSUser to send a confirmation mail in the newly created users' browserlanguage.

For this I'm saving the locate found by javascript in my database. 
Then, I'm setting my request to that locale and send the confirmation mail manually like this:

`$request->setLocale($locale); //($locale = 'en_US')
$mailer = $this->get('fosmailer');
$mailer->sendConfirmationEmailMessage($user);`

My email template contains a bunch of `{{ 'foobar' | trans}}` tags, which work perfectly fine. But I'm also using the `{{confirmationUrl}}` which is generated by FOSUser.

In an English mail this confirmation url will still show up as:

`/nl/registreren/confirm/1234..`

Any ideas why my mail is localized but my url isn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL address is not translated, because localization of URL addresses is not part of standard Symfony2 installation.

In order to localize URL addresses you need to use some bundle which solves this issue, for example [BeSimpleI18nRoutingBundle](http://knpbundles.com/BeSimple/BeSimpleI18nRoutingBundle) or you can create your own solution.