# Symfony 2.8 FOSUserBundle locale

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I have a site developed in Symfony 2.8 and I am using FOSUserBundle. The site is multilingual and the login form is offered in several languages.

I used the instructions as found on below links:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login.html

and

[Locale switch in login of FOSUserBundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17207463/locale-switch-in-login-of-fosuserbundle)

I added the locale prefix to the form in security.yml:

```
fos_user_security:
     resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"
     prefix: /{_locale}
```

The form works fine except one thing. After the login the user is always sent to the default locale which is English. He than needs to change the locale again his language.

How do I propagate the locale from the user login form to proper locale on user page. The user page is prefixed with the locale in routing.yml

```
user:
path: /{_locale}/user
defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Default:usermain }
requirements:
    _locale: en|hr
```

Comment: try with this [link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/session/locale_sticky_session.html)